# How to add a column in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

Creating text book and all I need is to add index (chapter numbers) in the first column and chapter names in the second. I have second column, cells etc., chapter names etc., ready and working. But reading Swift doc doesn't show how to add a first column. Can anyone point me to a doc where it has more info about it?

Comment: Question makes no sense. UITableView has only one column.

Comment: As @matt pointed, UITableView has only one column. If I understand correctly, you can implement your need with a custom cell with two labels on it

Comment: How did you add the second column before adding the first? Explain what you have actually done already.

Comment: I have created an array which contains all the chapter names. I have added this all in a table view controller. The build shows one column with all chapter names in it. In the first column I want numbers assigned to each chapter name. Thanks

Comment: So need to show column first .There is no way in table View to add column .

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you are looking for a custom cell which has two labels, where you can add a divider in between so it looks as if you have two columns. Implementing a custom cell is fairly challenging so [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVJiprvRLoo)'s a tutorial which I found helpful.

Comment: Instead of images dogs, etc. I just want to add numbers for each chapter. I checked out this and other tutorials yesterday all day. None of them show how to add numbers, They just show how to add images. There is some code available but, in Objective-C. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. It seems to me that you can just use labels (instead of an image view) and have it display your number. The video explains how to use labels in a custom cell.